# How to import Python Fuction data into Pandas Data-frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a code below which is just fetching the data from the `ldapsearch` command, now i am thinking about to use pandas to get data into a desired format but i am not getting how i can access the python function data into Pandas DataFrame.

### Code :

```
import subprocess

def UserID():
    LDP = "ldapsearch -h ldap.example.com -xLLLb 'ou=Personal,ou=People,ou=udalt' uid fullName"
    proc = subprocess.Popen(LDP, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    info_str = proc.stdout.read().decode('utf8')
    str_info = info_str.splitlines()
    prefixes = ["uid:", "fullName:"]
    for line in str_info:
        if line.startswith(tuple(prefixes)):
            lines = line
            for line in lines.splitlines():
                     print(line, end=' ' if line.startswith("uid:")  else "\n")
UserID()
```

### Result:

```
uid: khati06610 fullName: Anik sa
uid: khati06648 fullName: Vikur Doom
uid: khati06663 fullName: Gopi sa
uid: khati06718 fullName: Jeff kana
uid: khati10131 fullName: Peter j
uid: khati10152 fullName: Mie sean
```

### Desired Data From pandas Processing will be :

```
User ID        User Name
khati06610    Anik sa 
khati06648    Vikur Doom
khati06663    Gopi sa 
khati06718    Jeff kana
khati10131    Peter j 
khati10152    Mie sean
```

Comment: can you modify UserID func?

Comment: @Roim, I am okay to modify if you have any suggestion pls.

Comment: Maybe I'm naive, but why not parse the full string into two lists? one list to hold userid and second username. If you can do that, building dataframe from two list is easy. Can you parse each `line` to retrieve userId and username? like splitting on 'uid' and 'fullName'

Comment: @SaiSreenivas , its always alphabets and numbers indeed yes.

Comment: @Roim, appreciate your comment , yes that's another choice but just looking a way with pandas.

Answer (score 2):

try this, but the preferable way would be to use [`python-ldap`](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.3.0/) which provides an object-oriented API to access LDAP & avoid's the overhead of string parsing.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

search_ = re.compile("uid:\s(.*)\sfullName:\s(.*)")

print(
    pd.DataFrame(
        [{"User ID": u, "User Name": n} for u, n in search_.findall(line)]
    )
)
```

---

```
      User ID   User Name
0  khati06610     Anik sa
1  khati06648  Vikur Doom
2  khati06663     Gopi sa
3  khati06718   Jeff kana
4  khati10131     Peter j
5  khati10152    Mie sean
```